# Using ScrollView with LinearLayout, Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

In my xml file , i have one linearLayout and a button. The linearLayout contains a lot of textViews and checkboxes. So i wanted these textViews and checkboxes to scroll but the button should remain at its place i.e it should not scroll with the textViews. For this purpose, i cover my linearLayout with scrollView like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/homeo11" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
          <LinearLayout 
             android:id="@+id/nexttodetail"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" 
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

          </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>>

   <Button   android:id="@+id/Next4"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Next" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

But doing this , hid my button. means the textviews and checkboxes are now scrolling properly but i can't see my next button. I try replacing the scrollView layout:height from fill_parent to wrap_content but this didn't work as well. Any help?

Comment: use `android:layout_weight="1"` in scrollbar and button

Comment: If you instead user `RelativeLayout` as your outermost layout, you can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` inside the button to keep it at Bottom and always visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout as your root View and then set your component with align_above, align_parent_top and align_parent_bottom like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/homeo11" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"      
        android:layout_above="@+id/Next4" >       
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/nexttodetail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    (...)

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>>

   <Button  
       android:id="@+id/Next4"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"     
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="Next" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tried your code but using this hide my linearLayout stuff!